# Autoencoder accuracy with standardized data

Tags: neural-networks, standardization, autoencoders, relu

I want to make an autoencoder over the data that I originally standardized (that is, the data is now normally distributed ~ N(0,1)). The activation functions I use in the linear autoencoder is ReLu.
As I know that about 95% of the data after standardization is in the interval of $<-3,3>$ only by using the Relu function $max(0,x)$ will not be able to guess all the data.
One idea that came to my mind is to use bias, but as far as I understand, bias works inside the activation function, that is, $y = f(w^Tx + b)$, not $y = f(w^Tx) + b$ what kind of implementation in Pytorch.
Does anyone have another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the input of the network it's  fine to input normalized data. This is exactly what batch normalization does.

In the output layer you don't add an activation. Instead you output the values from the linear layer $w^Tx+b$. This is standard practice, and solves the problem of the negative values.